# Retain original point and text size in d3-3d scatterplot zoom

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js, 3d, scatter-plot

I am an absolute javascript noob and am trying to implement a zoom functionality on a d3-3d scatterplot (which is largely based off of [this example](https://bl.ocks.org/niekes/1c15016ae5b5f11508f92852057136b5)). I want the functionality to be able to zoom into overlapping, dense areas of points and inspect them with higher resolution. Currently, when zoomed, the size of the points and the text simply enlarges, not allowing for the desired higher resolution.

I am looking for some information on how to zoom and allow the scale to update with it, but no tutorials I am finding online are working out for me.

My code is available here:

https://jsfiddle.net/CKCMathCS613/n0p7gay3/

Currently the zoom is encapsulated into a `zoomed` function at the bottom of the script, but can be summarized with this simple call to d3.zoomTransform():

```
var svg = d3.select('svg').call(d3.zoom().on("zoom", function (){ svg.attr("transform", d3.zoomTransform(this))})).append('g');
```

I have tried so many things - from updating the scale using the `d3.event.transform.k` variable to hard coding the circle's `r` and text's `dx` attributes. But nothing works right.

I love how this example zooms: https://observablehq.com/@d3/zoom-canvas-rescaled but I cannot for the life of me incorporate their code into mine and get it to work.

After a couple days of banging my head against the wall, I'm hoping there is an easy solution to this one. Thanks in advance!

**EDIT: The jsfiddle has now been updated to a correct implementation of the problem, with correct scaling with zoom and rotation.**

Comment: Because you are applying a transform to the entire SVG, the points and text will scale. A solution would be dividing the text size / point radius by the zoom transform scale on each zoom event. This way the scaling of the SVG is cancelled by scaling the text and points in the reverse direction. Don’t have a device to demonstrate currently though.

Comment: Thanks for the response! I have tried something like `svg.selectAll('circle').attr("transform", d3.zoomTransform(this)).attr("r", svg.selectAll('cirlce').r / d3.event.transform.k);
    svg.selectAll('text').attr("transform", d3.zoomTransform(this)).attr("dx", svg.selectAll('text').dx / d3.event.transform.k);` but that doesn't seem to work... Was this along the lines of what you were proposing?

Comment: @AndrewReid I think I am getting somewhere with this. Applying the transform to the whole svg, and simply updating the `r` of the `circle` objects looks decent. The text size isn't updating in the same way: ```svg.attr("transform", d3.zoomTransform(this));
  
  svg.selectAll('circle').attr("r", 3 / d3.event.transform.k);
    
  svg.selectAll('text').attr("dx", 3 / d3.event.transform.k);``` but even with this, as soon as I rotate the svg and the rotate function is called, all sizing goes back to what it was pre-zoom.

Comment: realizing now that `dx` is absolutely the wrong attribute to update. `font-size` is doing the trick!

Comment: And just to close this - to get the rotate transform not to override the point size, I simply set the r to a variable (rather than a hardcoded number) and I update the variable within the zoom function. Then it does not get overwritten back to a hard coded default on rotations. Thanks for your help @AndrewReid!!!